# Python: How to use mock or patch to check that a method inside another method has run?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I've read through a whole bunch of answers, but still don't understand where I need to mock and/or which class/module to patch and keep getting `module does not have the attribute` errors.

I have a View class which contains a method I'd like to test. That method does not return anything. What it does is: checks an `if/else` statement based on the method's parameter, and in both cases fires off another method (imported from another module) with different args. I want to see if that inner method is being called with the correct arguments.

Here's the simplified code:

```py
from django.views import View
from django.conf import settings
from my_project import email

class ProcessSub(View):
    def handle_ineligible(ineligible_dict):
        if ineligible_dict["status"] == "NOT_FOUND":
            email.send_email(settings.NOT_FOUND_EMAIL_ID)
        else:
            email.send_email(settings.INELIGIBLE_EMAIL_ID)
```

What I want to do in my test is call `handle_ineligible` with a known `status` and check whether `email.send_email` was called with the right `EMAIL_ID`.

---

What I've tried:

```
@mock.patch('myproject.services.email.send_email')
    def test_not_found(self, mock_email_send):
    INELIGIBLE_DICT = {'status': 'NOT_FOUND'}
    view = ProcessSub()
    view.handle_ineligible(INELIGIBLE_DICT)
    mock_email_send.assert_called_with(settings.INELIGIBLE_EMAIL_ID)
```

This fails with the following AssertionError:

```
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: send_email('asdf')
E           Actual: not called.
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the tests that fails, instead of just obliquely describing them.

Comment: @chepner just added it in

Comment: Is the test in the same file as the class? If not, you are patching the wrong name `email`.

Comment: @chepner oh good point. update: I tried `@mock.patch(../../myproject/services/email.send_email)` - which is definitely where the module is located - and it threw a `ValueError: Empty module name`. Is there still an issue with how I'm writing the module correctly?

Comment: @chepner update: I got the module working `@mock.patch(myproject.services.email.send_email)`. However, this is still throwing an error, `AssertionError: expected call not found.` Basically, it doesn't think the inner function got called...